# Getting text between one or more pairs of strings using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a string between one or more pairs of string. For example,

```
import re
string1 = 'oi sdfdsf a'
string2 = 'biu serdfd e'
pattern = '(oi|biu)(.*?)(a|e)'
substring = re.search(pattern, string1).group(1)
```

In this case I should get: "sdfdsf" if I use string1 and "serdfd" if I use string2 in the search funnction. Instead I'm getting "oi" or "biu"

Comment: why not just `str.split`?

Comment: Your match is in Group 2. Just use `.group(2)` to get it. Just `.strip()` it afterwards, no need to complicate the regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you use string in parentheses, regex will capture your string. If you want capture some strings but not match of them, you should add '(?:)' expressions.

You can just changed your pattern as below.

```
pattern = '(?:oi|biu)[ /t]+([\w*]+)[ /t]+(?:a|e)'
```

Comment: That's indeed the simplest solution. You use a non-greedy captrue group. In this case `(.*?)` will capture any sequence of 0 or more characters until the start of the next capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You are placing capture groups around parts of your regex pattern which you don't really want to capture.  Consider this version:

```py
inp = ['oi sdfdsf a', 'biu serdfd e']
for i in inp:
    word = re.findall(r'\b(?:oi|biu) (\S+) (?:a|e)\b', i)[0]
    print(i + ' => ' + word)
```

Here we turn off the capture groups on the surrounding words on the left and right, and instead use a single capture group around the term you want to capture.  This prints:

```
oi sdfdsf a => sdfdsf
biu serdfd e => serdfd
```